# arranging widgets in cardview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, widget, android-cardview, cardview

I have placed widgets in my cardview but with changing screen sizes the widgets are also changing the positions. How can I be sure that the widgets will fit all screen sizes. I have used android:screenOrientation="nosensor" but still the widgets are misplaced with changing screen sizes. Please help with a solution. Will it support on tablet phones also?

```
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relative1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_70sdp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_70sdp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_6sdp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_6sdp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_6sdp"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/card_house" />
    
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView15"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/imageView7"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_8ssp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_4sdp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular"
                        android:padding="@dimen/_3ssp"
                        android:text="1346sqft"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp" />
    
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView21"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/textView15"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_8ssp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular"
                        android:padding="@dimen/_3ssp"
                        android:text="AGRICULTURE"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_8ssp" />
    
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/cardname"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_26sdp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_6ssp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView7"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular"
                        android:padding="@dimen/_2ssp"
                        android:text="xyz"
                        android:textColor="@color/black" />
    
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/cardnum"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/cardname"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_26sdp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_3ssp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_6ssp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView7"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular"
                        android:padding="@dimen/_2ssp"
                        android:text="98765544312"
                        android:textColor="@color/black" />
    
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/pidnum"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/cardnum"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_38sdp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_31ssp"
                        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/textView15"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular"
                        android:padding="@dimen/_3ssp"
                        android:text="123456"
                        android:textAlignment="gravity"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp" />
    
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/pidtxt"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/pidnum"
                        android:layout_marginStart="31dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_30ssp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/textView21"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="@dimen/_3ssp"
                        android:text="PID NO"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_8ssp" />
    
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/sitenum"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_38ssp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_83ssp"
                        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/pidnum"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="@dimen/_3ssp"
                        android:text="986"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp" />
    
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/sitetxt"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/sitenum"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_43ssp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/pidtxt"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular"
                        android:padding="@dimen/_3ssp"
                        android:text="SITE NO"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_8ssp" />
    
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/sasnum"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_60ssp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_82ssp"
                        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/sitenum"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular"
                        android:padding="@dimen/_3ssp"
                        android:text="1/134"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp" />
    
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/sasnum"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_47ssp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/sitetxt"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular"
                        android:padding="@dimen/_3ssp"
                        android:text="SAS APPN NO"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_8ssp" />
             </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

[image: Below is the cardview]

Answer (score 0):

Well, Android Studio provides different ways to preview your layout. You can choose on which device it is previewed. From small devices with 5.0" to 10.1" (you can go with even more configurations since list of virtual devices is even broader, recently I've been testing app on 4" virtual device with use of AVD).

[image: Android Studio preview devices list]

Comment: After checking on different AVD's Im asking how can I make the cardview responsive to fit all screen sizes..You havnt got my question.